# jQuery selector with special characters passed as variable doesn't seems to be work

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a Problem passing a variable with special characters into a jQuery selector.
To simplify the following code is used.

The element looks like:

```
<div class="S3#123#568745" /> some_text  </div>
```

The following selector works fine:

```
$(".S3\\#123\\#568745")
```

This selector doesn't works and i don't know why:

```
    var class_id = ".S3#123#568745";
    class_id = class_id.replace(/#/g,'\\\\#');

    $(class_id)  //doesn't work

    console.log(class_id); //shows ".S3\\#123\\#568745"
```

Any Ideas ?

http://jsfiddle.net/hnr3R/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out
Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnr3R/3/)

**Javascript**:

```
var class_id = ".S3#123#568745";
class_id = class_id.replace(/#/g,"\\#");

$("#result1").text($(class_id).text())
```

Comment: Thx! it works. i'am confused a little bit because the output of class_id shows ".S3\#123\#568745" and jQuery docu says double \ for special characters needed. Can you explain this issue?

Comment: @Christoph Well, I am not quite sure why did it work like this. I would appreciate if someone can shed some light on this